# How to write this sql query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the (orderno, payby, idno) from table1 where the idno is the max and payby is not 'ROUNDING'.

```
orderno | payby | idno
01,CASH,1
01,ROUNDING,2
03,CASH,1
03,ROUNDING,2
03,CASH,3
11,CASH,1
11,CASH,2
11,EFTPOS,3
```

Result should be like this:

```
01,CASH,1
03,CASH,3
11,EFTPOS,3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from `table1` where payby != 'ROUNDING' and (orderno,idno) in (
select orderno, max(idno) from `table1` where payby != 'ROUNDING' group by orderno )
```

The inner sel should give you all orderno with his max idno. The outer select should gives you the row for this data.

Answer (score 0):

In the result should be also 11,CASH,2  , right?

```
select orderno,payby,MAX(Idno) as Idno from #yourtable 
where payby != 'ROUNDING' group by orderno,payby
```

You will group by orderno,payby and get the max value for Idno plusyou dont want payby to be "Rounding" so you do `where payby != 'ROUNDING'`